# How to have a "multi" object handler of a class or object?

Tags: python-3.x, oop

**Edit:** The more I think of edge cases, the less useful it seems to be. I'll leave this open because I find it interesting, but I understand that it is not really a good thing to do.

I would like to take several objects of a certain class, combine them into a sort of 'multi-object' of the same class, which essentially gets the child class's same attributes. I'm not sure how to explain it, so here's an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def bar(self, y):
        print(self.x)
        return 2 * y


f1 = Foo(2)
f2 = Foo(3)
f3 = Foo(5)
f4 = Foo(7)

def multi(*args):
    if len(args) == 0:
        raise ValueError("Requires at least one object")
    if not all(isinstance(arg, type(args[0])) for arg in args):
        raise TypeError("All objects must be the same type")
    # ... magic

multi_f = multi(f1, f2, f3, f4)

assert multi_f.x == [2, 3, 5, 7]  # attributes return a list of each of the objects in the multi_f
assert multi_f.bar(y=5) == [10, 10, 10, 10]  #  prints 2 then 3 then 5 then 7 but "5" is passed to all of them
```

I initially though of overriding `__getattr__` and friends, but thought of all of the other functions you'd have to override and wondered if there was a better way.

Another alternative for the bar function could be such that each function would get it's own parameters, but these are mutually exclusive:

```
assert multi_f.bar([
    [[], dict(y=5)],
    [[], dict(y=10)],
    [[], dict(y=20)],
    [[], dict(y=40)],
]) == [10, 20, 40, 80]
```

With this idea, however, you'd have to splat the list and dict into each of the object's function calls.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fun idea! So this solution below uses a class (`Multi`) (since we're creating a 'multi' *object*, it should be an actual object). I've only implemented `__getattr__`, but *I think* you should be able to override other methods as you need them (eg. `__setattr__` if you want to assign, `__eq__` to test for equality, etc.) - this would require a lot of planning to decide exactly how each should act though!

```
class Multi:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.foos = args

    def __getattr__(self, key, *args, **kwargs):
        ret = []
        # two options - accessing values, or methods to call
        # this boolean decides which type to return (i'm sure there's a neater way, but this was quick)
        wrap = False

        # build a list of the attributes from foos
        for foo in self.foos:
            x = getattr(foo, key)
            if callable(x):
                wrap = True
            ret.append(x)

        # return an anonymous function that when called, returns a list
        # with the result of calling each callable with whatever args/kwargs
        if wrap:
            return lambda *args, **kwargs: [x(*args, **kwargs) for x in ret]

        # otherwise just return the list of values
        return ret

multi_f = Multi(f1, f2, f3, f4)
assert multi_f.x == [2, 3, 5, 7]  # attributes return a list of each of the objects in the multi_f
assert multi_f.bar(y=5) == [10, 10, 10, 10]  #  prints 2 then 3 then 5 then 7 but "5" is passed to all of them
```

I believe the last option you suggest would be possible, but yeah, they couldn't both be implemented at the same time unless you used an extra argument as a flag/toggle switch.

Comment: Yes, I agree, and this is similar to what I have done, although I ended up using `type` and created a class inline. This, however, does seem cleaner. Thanks for your response!